# How can i retain values in the previous page when user navigate to nextpage

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I have RadGrid with template field.In this i have textboxes.The user will enter values in textbox.The radgrid has paging option.How can i retain values in the previous page when user navigate to nextpage.How can i handle this?.Whether i need to save the details temporarly

Answer (score 0):

yes, you have to save data temporary manually.

Let me know if you need any help.